# Can't bind to any ports (Devuan)

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, port

I recently experienced problems establishing an SSH tunnel. It turned out that also neither Apache nor Nginx won't bind to any ports (even as root and/or outside the <1024 range).
From [here](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/c_c++/socket.htm) I got a small test program (right below *Sample Code*; my version with output below), hoping I could track down the error. However, running `./server 6789` and `./client localhost 6789` (in two terminals on the same machine) gives no errors. There is just no connection, so `server` blocks in `accept()`:

```
Server:
socket().
bzero().
htons().
bind().
listen().
```

```
Client:
socket().
gethostbyname().
bzero().
bcopy().
htons().
ERROR connecting: Connection timed out
```

The output statements are mine. They are the only thing I've changed, being printed after each successful command.

Apache and Nginx behave similarly, you just can't connect to the server.
However, with SSH there is an error:

```
$ ssh -4 -vvv -NL 5901:"$server":5901 "$user@$server"
[...]
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <server> ([<ip>]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:5901 forwarded to remote address <server>:5901
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5901.
bind: Cannot assign requested address
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 5901
Could not request local forwarding.
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
```

(Without `-4`, the output is slightly different but basically the same.)

Anki behaves similarly:

```
$ anki
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "aqt/mediasrv.py", line 57, in run
  File "socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
  File "aqt/mediasrv.py", line 38, in server_bind
  File "socketserver.py", line 467, in server_bind
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

**Any idea what's the issue here or how I could track down the error?**

With Devuan Jessie it has been working, and also on another PC running Devuan ASCII as well. I already checked if a package is missing that is there on the other installations, but didn't find anything that seemed relevant (I have `netbase`).

Thanks!

server.cpp:

```
/* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    puts("Server:");
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    puts("socket().");
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    puts("bzero().");
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    puts("htons().");
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
             sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR on binding");
    puts("bind().");
    listen(sockfd,5);
    puts("listen().");
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR on accept");
    puts("accept().");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
    n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0; 
}
```

client.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    puts("Client:");

    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    puts("socket().");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    puts("gethostbyname().");
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    puts("bzero().");
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    puts("bcopy().");
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    puts("htons().");
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It said it was down. I did `ifup lo` and now it works. Thank you! :)

Comment: Did so. Are you helping me earning some reputation or is there another reason you didn't answer it yourself?

Comment: The former. I tend to write long explanatory answers and I've got enough reputation already. Since the fix (`ifup lo`) is your input, it's perfectly fine it's in your answer. I find encouraging such short (yet useful) self-answers a good way to make newcomers blend in.

Answer (score 1):

The output from `ip addr show lo` indicated that the loopback interface wasn't running, so a quick fix was

```
sudo ifup lo
```